# make: *** [ffmpeg_movie.lo] Error 1 when compiling ffmpeg-php

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I've basically exhausted myself searching Google and trying to address an error I get when compiling ffmpeg-php on a CentOS / 6.4-64 with PHP 5.4.20 and Apache v2.2.25 (cgi-fcgi).

I end up getting the following when trying to compile.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix/address this?

```
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:311: error: âlist_entryâ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:311: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:311: error: for each function it appears in.)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:311: error: âleâ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:346: error: expected â;â before ânew_leâ
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:356: error: ânew_leâ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c: In function âzim_ffmpeg_movie_getCommentâ:
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:531: warning: âcommentâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/l                                                                                          ibavformat/avformat.h:760)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:531: warning: âcommentâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/l                                                                                          ibavformat/avformat.h:760)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c: In function âzim_ffmpeg_movie_getTitleâ:
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:546: warning: âtitleâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/lib                                                                                          avformat/avformat.h:757)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:546: warning: âtitleâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/lib                                                                                          avformat/avformat.h:757)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c: In function âzim_ffmpeg_movie_getAuthorâ:
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:561: warning: âauthorâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/li                                                                                          bavformat/avformat.h:758)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:561: warning: âauthorâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/li                                                                                          bavformat/avformat.h:758)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c: In function âzim_ffmpeg_movie_getCopyrightâ:
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:575: warning: âcopyrightâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include                                                                                          /libavformat/avformat.h:759)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:575: warning: âcopyrightâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include                                                                                          /libavformat/avformat.h:759)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c: In function âzim_ffmpeg_movie_getAlbumâ:
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:590: warning: âalbumâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/lib                                                                                          avformat/avformat.h:761)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:590: warning: âalbumâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/lib                                                                                          avformat/avformat.h:761)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c: In function âzim_ffmpeg_movie_getGenreâ:
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:604: warning: âgenreâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/lib                                                                                          avformat/avformat.h:764)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:604: warning: âgenreâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/lib                                                                                          avformat/avformat.h:764)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c: In function âzim_ffmpeg_movie_getTrackNumberâ:
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:619: warning: âtrackâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:763)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c: In function âzim_ffmpeg_movie_getYearâ:
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:632: warning: âyearâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:762)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c: In function â_php_read_av_frameâ:
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:1215: warning: âavcodec_decode_videoâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/l                                                                                          ocal/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:3656)
make: *** [ffmpeg_movie.lo] Error 1

Answer (score 6):

after ripping my eyeballs out... this will fix the problem:

Changes in ffmpeg_movie.c:

- row 311: `list_entry *le;` to `zend_rsrc_list_entry *le;`
- row 346: `list_entry new_le;` to `zend_rsrc_list_entry new_le;`
- row 360: `hashkey_length+1, (void *)&new_le, sizeof(list_entry),` to `hashkey_length+1, (void *)&new_le,sizeof(zend_rsrc_list_entry),`

Thats all... change it and make it

Comment: you have to vim ffmpeg_movie.c in ssh to be able to do this fyi